# How can I make my HTML template useful for more than 1 table?

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have an HTML file that I've made which contains a template for a table.

```
<body>

**#HeadingGoesHere#**

<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            **#TableHeading#**      
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    **#TableBody#**
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    **#TableTotals#**
    </tfoot>
</table>
</body>
```

I have a PHP program that uses str_replace to populate the table.  This is great for creating 1 table, however I would need to make this possible for 1 or more tables.  With my HTML template as is, I don't believe it is possible, since it only allows for one table to be created, when I'll need to create 1 or multiple tables.

I'm not very experienced in HTML and PHP, so I'm unsure if there is a way to do this using an HTML template, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: Tables can vary enormously. If you want to generate them using PHP why not use OOP? For example: https://github.com/donquixote/cellbrush Haven't used this myself, but it seems easy to use. There are many more generators like this out there, or you could write your own.

Comment: Remove the body tag. Then you've got a re-usable snippet you can insert as many times as you like into a bigger document. P.s. there are many templates engines available for php (and javascript) already. I'd be wary of reinventing what already exists and is likely more mature than your solution- unless you have some specific requirements that the existing tools can't satisfy, of course

Answer (score 0):

I would go with an existing solution using the DOM.
This will allow you the flexibility you need, plus ensure you output HTML is well formed.
This basic example below, shows how you might get started, and creates a reusable class you can use to generate any table in any project.

```
<?php
    
        class table extends DomDocument{
    
            /**
             * This variable holds the table
             * @access      private
             */
            private $table;
    
            /**
             * Constructor, sets up the root element
             */
            public function __construct(){
                    parent::__construct();
                    $table = self::createElement('table');
                    $this->table = parent::appendChild($table);
            }
    
            /**
             * Appends a child to the root node ($table)
             * @access      public
             * @param       domNode $child
             * @return      void
             */
            public function appendChild(domNode $child):void {
                    $this->table->appendChild($child);
            }
    
            /**
             * Returns a string representation of the table
             * @access      public
             * @return      string
             */
            public function __toString() :string{
                    return parent::saveHTML();
            }
    }

    $table = new table;
    
    // create the <thead>
    $thead = $table->createElement('thead');
    // create the table column headings
    $th = $table->createElement('th', 'Heading 1');
    $thead->appendChild($th);
    $th = $table->createElement('th', 'Heading 1');
    $thead->appendChild($th);
    $th = $table->createElement('th', 'Heading 1');
    $thead->appendChild($th);
    // add the head to the table
    
    
    // create the <tbody>
    $tbody = $table->createElement('tbody');
    
    // create a table row
    $tr = $table->createElement('tr');
    // create a table data cell
    $td = $table->createElement('td', 'Col1 Row 1');
    $tr->appendChild($td);
    $td = $table->createElement('td', 'Col2 Row 1');
    $tr->appendChild($td);
    $td = $table->createElement('td', 'Col3 Row 1');
    $tr->appendChild($td);
    // add the above row to the tbody
    $tbody->appendChild($tr);
    // create a second table row
    $tr = $table->createElement('tr');
    // create a table data cell
    $td = $table->createElement('td', 'Col1 Row 2');
    $tr->appendChild($td);
    $td = $table->createElement('td', 'Col2 Row 2');
    $tr->appendChild($td);
    $td = $table->createElement('td', 'Col3 Row 2');
    $tr->appendChild($td);
    // add the above row to the tbody
    $tbody->appendChild($tr);
    
    
    // create the <tfoot>
    $tfoot = $table->createElement('tfoot');
    // create the table column headings
    $th = $table->createElement('th', 'Foot 1');
    $thead->appendChild($th);
    $th = $table->createElement('th', 'Foot 2');
    $thead->appendChild($th);
    $th = $table->createElement('th', 'Foot 3');
    $tfoot->appendChild($th);
    
    // add the thead to the table
    $table->appendChild($thead);
    // add the tbody to the table
    $table->appendChild($tbody);
    // add the tfoot to the table
    $table->appendChild($tfoot);
    echo $table;
```